# Netbeans "waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)" on Mac 10.8.5

Tags: php, macos, netbeans

I've setup Netbeans & Xdebug several times on a windows machine, but this is my first time on a mac. Should be pretty much the same, but I can't get it going.

**My php.ini settings:**

```
zend_extension="/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
1922 [xdebug]
1923 xdebug.remote_autostart=0
1924 xdebug.remote_enable=1
1925 xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
1926 xdebug.remote_mode="req"
1927 xdebug.remote_port=9002
1928 xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
1929 xdebug.profiler_enable=0
1930 xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/"
1931 xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
1932 xdebug.remote_log="/home/mmutrux/xdebug.log"
```

**This loads up in the phpinfo:**

[image]

**My Netbeans settings use the same port (9002)**
[image]

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Xdebug will only connect if I run it on my index.php file.

I started with a plain `index.html` file and a `getData.php` file.  Running the debugger on `getData.php` did not work until i added an index php page and ran the debugger on that.  From that point on (with the debugger running) I could set breakpoints on all other php files and get the expected behavior.

[image]